# Is there any plugin or short cut to Clean + Build + Run in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

For a slightly larger project solution often we need to clean and build after each change. If there is a shortcut like the Play symbol in the visual studio that would really save a lot of time.

As of now, we have to clean the solution first which takes 4-5 seconds and then re-build which takes 30 seconds and then wait for it to run. This kills 2-3 minutes easily.

Comment: If you need to "clean and build after each change" then I'd hazard to suggest your projects/solutions aren't correctly configured :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to automate it:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
{
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.CleanSolution");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.Start");
}
```